# problem with thickness of hline

Tags: tables

[image]I am having problem with the thickness of hline. all hline in the code suppose to generate same thickness in the table but some of them are generating different thickness in the same table. here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{List of video tutorials}
      \label{tab:videoTutorials}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
          Tutorial Description &
         Length & Number of Comments\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} \\ \hline
        Putting two pictures together & 5:39 & 235 \\
        Fire text effect & 6:00 & 123 \\
        Splatter effect in a photo & 6:39 & 115 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textasteriskcentered] As of May 15, 2015
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines have the same thickness. Very likely the problem is only caused by the PDF viewer, when at low resolution the number of pixels differs because of rounding.

Package `booktabs` provides nicer thinner lines with some space around, the `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` are a little thicker than `\midrule` by default.

The following example shows the original table, where the lines have the same thickness, and the table below shows the version via package `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{List of video tutorials}
      \label{tab:videoTutorials}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
          Tutorial Description &
         Length & Number of Comments\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} \\ \hline
        Putting two pictures together & 5:39 & 235 \\
        Fire text effect & 6:00 & 123 \\
        Splatter effect in a photo & 6:39 & 115 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textasteriskcentered] As of May 15, 2015
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}

    \vspace{5mm}

    \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \toprule
          Tutorial Description &
         Length & Number of Comments\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} \\
        \midrule
        Putting two pictures together & 5:39 & 235 \\
        Fire text effect & 6:00 & 123 \\
        Splatter effect in a photo & 6:39 & 115 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[\textasteriskcentered] As of May 15, 2015
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks for the solution. I tried booktabs and getting similar results. But after zooming in I found that actually them have same width. probably problem caused by the pdf viewer. thanks for the insight :)